# Logic Help for function Move up and Down in a listview

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, servicemanager

I am using a poco class for the following screen but im just wondering how I would achieve the move up and down elements of this screen[image]

I am using ObservableCollection to add my items to a mutual list my question is how would I achieve the move up and move down. I no I would need to change the poco class in real time but not sure how I would achieve this

```
   private void AddColumn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.WizardData == null)
            return;

        if (this.WizardData.ConcreteCustomColumnsProxy == null)
            this.WizardData.ConcreteCustomColumnsProxy = new ObservableCollection<CustomColumnsModel>();

        this.WizardData.ConcreteCustomColumnsProxy.Add(new CustomColumnsModel() { CustomColumnsDisplayName = txtDsiplayName.Text
            , CustomColumnsOrder = 1, CustomColumnsWidth = Convert.ToInt32(txtWdith.Text) });

        this.listView1.ItemsSource = this.WizardData.ConcreteCustomColumnsProxy;
        this.listView1.UnselectAll();

        this.listView1.Items.Refresh();
```

My Poco class is as follows

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public const string IdPropertyName = "CustomColumnsID";
    private Guid _Id = Guid.Empty;
    public Guid CustomColumnsID
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set
        {
            if (_Id == value)
                return;
            _Id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(IdPropertyName);
        }
    }


    public string CustomColumnsDisplayName { get; set; }
    public int CustomColumnsWidth { get; set; }
    public int CustomColumnsOrder { get; set; }  


    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string key)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(key));
        }
    }

    public EnterpriseManagementObject ActualData { get; private set; }

}
```

Comment: This question and its two siblings are being discussed on Meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270904/what-is-going-on-with-these-3-questions-about-wpf-reorganising-lists?noredirect=1#comment91513_270904 
@Fry: You may like to participate/view the discussion to learn more about how the site operates and how to product better questions.

Answer (score 4):

You have some sort of `DataGrid` control. You need to data bind a collection property to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property and a property of the same type as the items in the collection to the `DataGrid.SelectedItems` property:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollectionProperty}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding YourItemProperty}" />
```

With the `DataGrid.SelectedItems` property data bound to your `YourItemProperty`, you can set which item is selected in the UI by setting this property. So to move the selected item down one position, you could do something like this:

```
int selectedIndex = YourCollectionProperty.IndexOf(YourItemProperty);
if (YourCollectionProperty.Count > selectedIndex) 
    YourItemProperty = YourCollectionProperty.ElementAt(selectedIndex + 1);
```

So that is how you perform the actions of the 'Move Down' `Button` and the 'Move Up' `Button` would work similarly. Then all you would need to do is to hook up some `Click` or `ICommand` event handlers.

Comment: Doenst really help explainatio of what YourItemProperty is and how this is relvanant to the listview as explained was using wpf and listview

Comment: Firstly, you're welcome to the time that I spent on your answer. Secondly, really? Try reading it again: I said *You need to data bind a collection property to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property **and a property of the same type as the items in the collection to the `DataGrid.SelectedItems` property***. Can you see it now?

Comment: As I said I was already using that method with a oberservationcollection !

Comment: Wow, you really are a rude member... I vaguely remember having a similar altercation with you before. If you spent more time reading my answer than whining, you could have worked out how to fulfil your requirements from it. I really have no inclination in helping such a rude and ignorant user any further.

Comment: Thank you @PatrickHofman... it's good to know that not *all* of my many hours helping on this website has been wasted.

Comment: lest stack saw it was serial voting ;-0 vindicated